# Group with only one non-trivial orbit size

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, definition

Suppose I have a finite group $G\leq \mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$, and all of $G$'s orbits on $\Omega$ have size 1 or $|G|$.

Is there a name for this property? I think if there is only one orbit of size 1, then the group is Frobenius.

Comment: Frobenius groups are transitive, so they have no orbits of size $1$. The point stabilizer $H$ of  a Frobenius group is an example of the type you describe, with a single orbit of size $1$.

Comment: On the other hand, let $G$ be an arbitrary group, let $\alpha \notin G$, let $\Omega = \{ \alpha \} \cup G$, and consider $G \le \operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)$, fixing $\alpha$, and acting by (right, say) multiplication on itself. So, unless I am mistaken, it seems that your condition does not imply any restrictions on $G$.

Comment: Indeed, one can ignore the fixed points and just look at the ones of size $|G|$. These have stabilizer $1$, and so up to reordering the points $\{1,\dots,n\}$ we find that $g\in G$ acts as a bunch of copies of the regular representation, followed by fixing a few points at the end.

Comment: Great, thank you.